# Can not find 'MathJax' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am transitioning a Vue 3 website from Javascript to TypeScript. Mathjax is loaded from a CDN, and this field from a custom component which worked previously:

```
watch: {
    note_content: function () {
        this.$nextTick(MathJax.typesetPromise);
    }
}
```

now generates a static error which should translate as:

```
Can not find name 'MathJax'.ts(2304)
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install [@types/mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mathjax)

Comment: Thank you. However now I get "property 'typesetPromise' does not exist on type 'typeof MathJax'.ts(2339)", is there an easy fix ?